# Can I set printer defaults by program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printing

I've got a Canon MP600 which has a paper cassette as well as the auto sheet feeder. I want to keep one filled with photo paper and one with plain but don't want to waste my ink and paper accidentally printing to the wrong one so I'd like Photoshop Elements to default to use the photo paper and everything else to use the plain paper.

Any thoughts?

I'm using Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's not going to be any easy way (if there even is one). Windows handles print spooling and nearly every application will outsource printing to the OS spooler out of convenience.

Properties like paper type and paper source are exposed by the printer driver, and while they may be fairly common and standard on most printers today they aren't required to be supported in order for printing to work. This means that the default print dialogs don't expose them, thus explaining why you always have to click Properties to bring up your printer settings directly in order to change it. Printer driver settings are global, though, so unless your printer drivers themselves have some fancy per-application profile manager of some kind, no dice.

Maybe someone else knows of a third-party program of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

I routinely have multiple 'copies' of the 'same' printer (one simplex/single sided, one duplex/double-sided, one stapled, one printing onto [pre-printed] Letterhead, whatever).

Sounds like my solution for 'letterhead' would solve your issue, as well.

Basically, on *all* of the different 'versions' of the printer, I say that that paper tray is NOT AVAILABLE.
  Therefor, none of those other versions (1- or 2-sided, stapled, whatever) can possibly print on that kind of paper.
  Then, for the letterhead--or in your case, photo--printer, I say that *ALL* of the other paper trays are NOT available...  and ONLY that, one, specific, tray, IS.

Now, anything that I print to my 'letterhead' printer (or 'photo', in your case), comes out on letterhead.  Only.  Ever.  And I get notified if the tray is empty, because it's the only tray that exists.

And anything that I print to , will NEVER arrive on letterhead.  Ever.  Because none of them even recognize that the tray even has paper in it.

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase you answer to make it more clear HOW to accomplish this? Right now it sounds as though you might have a good idea here, but while there's a lot of relevant information, there are no clear steps to solve the problem proposed by OP.